# Inheriting from a React class created using createClass

Tags: javascript, inheritance, reactjs

I'm using a 3rd party library (Formsy), and I'd like to patch it's React class so that I can override one of the functions that it defines (`validate`).

I was expecting this to be quite simple:

```
Formsy.Form.prototype.validate = function(component) {
   console.log('test');
}
```

But that doesn't work. The child form components still call the original function (provided by the Forms.Form via the child context)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Formly is a mixin, and therefore its properties are added to "this", you can just override that property right on the instance created by React.CreateClass. But that wouldnt automatically apply to all instances using this Mixin

```
const MyInput = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Formsy.Mixin],
  changeValue(event) {
    this.setValue(event.currentTarget[this.props.type === 'checkbox' ? 'checked' : 'value']);
  },
  validate: function(){
     console.log('validating');
  },
```